# Exporting PDF from QGIS with print composer without destroying fonts

Tags: qgis, labeling, illustrator, font

So I'm making this nice map with a lot of labels which are going to end up in a book. Since the labels doesn't end up exactly where I want them I'd like to move them some in Illustrator after exporting them using the Print composer. The only problem is that when exporting to PDF the text is not text anymore, QGIS transforms it into paths instead of leaving the font alone.

Does anyone know a workaround so the labels stays as fonts when opening the image in Illustrator?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "paths"? There is a setting to print as raster, normally this is off, which is how you should have it.

Comment: The text breaks down into vector graphics instead of a  font object. For instance now it's impossible to switch font in Illustrator since they all are just vector paths.

Comment: I am not familiar with Illustrator, I use nitroPDF and it reproduces the fonts fine and allows editing. You might also try Inkscape and the GIMP but I can't speak from experience about them. Which font in particular?

Comment: See the QGIS ticket http://hub.qgis.org/issues/3975

Comment: @Willy Illustrator can convert fonts into paths which can remove issues when moving pdf files to other companies without the original font (licencing maybe required to share third party fonts)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been an issue for a while, ever since the new labeling engine has been used. Recently, the development version of QGIS has a new render setup that allows this bug to be reasonably fixed.

See: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/3975

The [fixed code changes are up for review](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/1286) for inclusion into the core codebase. When that happens, the feature will be available in the nightly releases, for testing.

There are still some scaling and font-embedding issues to be ironed out, but the feature essentially works now. Regardless, the fix should make it into the next release (QGIS 2.4).

Comment: Thanks! And you're the one making the nightly ones for Mac?

Comment: Oh and also, this feature will not be in 2.3? How long do I need to wait for 2.4 then? Oh my...

Comment: It will be in 2.3 (development version) prior to 2.4 release. Yes, I manage the nightly builds for Mac.

Comment: Could you do a shout out here when the feature is in the nightly builds? Or is it already?

Comment: Should be in nightlies in about a week or so, though there will be scaling issues until we work through adding more unit tests. It is going to be integrated with a better SVG export functionality.

Comment: Tried the the last nights nightly build and it looks like it's getting closer to be implemented, but not really yet? When I export to SVG I get the option "Render text as outline". The only problem is that this button is dimmed so I can't untick that box it. Is this just a problem for me?

Comment: Yes, it is not pushed to master yet.

Comment: Any news on this? It seems like it still doesn't work in version 2.4 and not in the recent nightly builds either.

Comment: wohoo! found this finally: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4058089/qgis/text-as-text_option.png

Answer (score 0):

Instead of exporting as a .pdf, export it as a .svg this will allow you to edit all the text and the lines in illustrator.
To get the text at the same size, in Qgis and illustrator you can set the size in points, not map units and it will show up witht the same font size in illustrator.

Comment: The only problem will be that some items will appear outside of the print area and will require a bit of tidying up in illustrator

Comment: Even when I export as SVG the fonts turn into vectors that can't be edited as a font. I have use version 2.2.

Comment: How are you labelling your features?
I label mine using the Layer Properites and Labels (deprecated), then I choose which attribute I want to be labelled. Either that or I create a new point layer and have that as a labelling layer, it also lets me move the labels around

Comment: Apparently the old label engine doesn't create vectors. Unfortunately the new one does. Using 2.2 here. You?

Comment: Yes, I am using 2.2 and my text comes out as editable text in illustrator. Although i dont use the labels option, i use Labels (deprecated)

Comment: Hmm OK, but where do I find the old label engine?

Comment: I dont think you will find it on 2.2. If you want to label something that can be edited in illustrator i would create a new vector layer that is a point. Under New attribute name it whatever you want with text data and width of 80 and add to attributes list. delete the "id" one that is automatically created. Once your new layer is created go into the properties and change layer transpararency to 100% and in labels (deprecated) select display labels."field containing label" will be your new attribute. Then just add points on your new layer and make sure your label is written in the attributes

Comment: this is the labelling technique I have used since 1.7. I just did a test on 2.2 and labels gave me uneditable text, whereas labels (deprecated) was editable

Comment: If you want the old label engine you can create a drawing in an older version and this should give you the option to use labels (deprecated)in the later version